# Checkout a specific older version of the source code through Subversion?

Tags: svn, macos

My project is currently at release (that is, r1000), and that is what is checked out to my local repository.

I would like to checkout a much older version to my repository, for purposes of performance comparison (for example, r500).

I have taken my tests and gotten results with r1000.

What svn commands do I need to use to get r500 into my local repository to run the same tests as on r1000?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You can update to a given revision using the r-parameter (or --revision)

```
svn update -r500
```

Comment: Didn't work for me. The answer below seems working: http://stackoverflow.com/a/13619486/1177964

Answer (score 25):

You can specifically checkout an older version of the repository by using:

```
svn checkout URL@revision
```

which, in your case, it would be:

```
svn checkout URL@500
```

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer did not work for me. The solution is:

```
svn up -r REVISION_NUMBER
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily get the revision using:

```
svn co -r revisionno svn://URL Foldername
```

For example,

```
svn co -r 1041 svn://192.168.x.x/ProjectName Revision1041
```

Comment: Yes, `checkout` works in this way! And in contrast to `update` it does not require an already existing "blessed" folder...

Answer (score 1):

We can do it using the following commands.

1. Get the old versions using the `svn log` command:

   ```
   manjeet-laptop:trunk manjeet$ svn log

   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   r1747 | pramod | 2014-01-10 15:01:17 +0530 (Fri, 10 Jan 2014) | 1 line
   ```

   Update new MSISDN series

   ```
   ------------------------------------------------------------------------
   r1742 | pramod | 2014-01-10 12:05:44 +0530 (Fri, 10 Jan 2014) | 1 line
   ```
2. Update the revision (say we want to get r1747)

   ```
   svn update -r1747
   ```